# ¿Cómo puedo generar un tren de pulsos con amplitud y tiempo muerto aleatorio?

Tags: python, matlab

Lo que pasa es que quiero implementar un generador de pulsos aleatorios ya sea en python o matlab y no sé cómo hacer para codificar esto.

Lo que me gustaría obtener es algo así, con amplitud y tiempo muerto aleatorio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien puede instruirme o proporcionarme algún referente para hacerlo estaría muy agradecido. Yo estaba explorando la opción de `scipy.signal.gausspulse` de python, sin embargo lo que obtengo es un pulso gaussiano modulado.

Comment: Si los flancos de subida pueden ser prácticamente verticales (es decir, que la señal varía abruptamente de un instante a otro), entonces debería ser relativamente sencillo. Si los flancos han de tener una curva gradual como la que has dibujado ya no sabría. Para lo primero de todas formas aún queda por definir la duración de la meseta (la parte en que es distinto de cero) ¿es la misma en todos los pulsos? ¿Ha de ser también aleatoria?

Comment: Los flancos no deben tener curva, la duración puede ser la misma, es solo para visualizar. El único parámetro que importa es la amplitud de los pulsos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con los supuestos siguientes (confirmados en un comentario):

- Los flancos de subida y bajada pueden ser perfectamente verticales.
- La duración de los pulsos puede ser la misma en todos.
- La distancia entre pulsos es aleatoria
- La altura del pulso es aleatoria

Entonces un algoritmo sencillo podría ser:

- Inicializar un array con ceros para toda la duración del periodo de tiempo a graficar
- Ir avanzando en ese array a "saltos" de longitud aleatoria y en cada salto:

  - Generar un valor al azar (la altura del pulso)
  - Rellenar varios elementos contiguos con ese valor

Este algoritmo se implementaría en el siguiente código, en el que he creado una serie de variables iniciales para permitir parametrizar el aspecto general:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

duracion_total = 1000
duracion_pulso = 20

# Variación en la altura de los pulsos
amplitud_max = 30
amplitud_min = 5

# Variación en la distancia entre pulsos
distancia_max = 200
distancia_min = 50

data = np.zeros(duracion_total)
muerto = np.random.randint(distancia_min, distancia_max)
x = muerto
while x<duracion_total:
  altura = np.random.randint(amplitud_min, amplitud_max)
  data[x:x+duracion_pulso] = altura
  muerto = np.random.randint(distancia_min, distancia_max)
  x += muerto
```

El array `data` resultante está listo para graficarse, y tendría esta pinta:

```py
plt.plot(data)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches((20, 4))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Actualización

Para unos pulsos menos cuadrados, y dado que ya estás usando `scypi` para otras cosas, se me ocurre la siguiente estrategia:

- Preparamos un array lleno de ceros como en la estrategia anterior
- Usamos la función `scypy.signal.gausspulse()` para generar un pulso de altura 1, centrado en 0, y con un cierto ancho y lo tenemos guardado en una variable.
- Sumamos al array de ceros el pulso calculado, pero desplazado una posición aleatoria en horizontal (podemos usar `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.shift`) y reescalado verticalmente una cantidad aleatoria.
- Repetimos el último paso varias veces para generar varios pulsos

Esta nueva estrategia se implementa con el siguiente código:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.interpolation import shift

duracion_total = 1000
ancho_pulso = 15
amplitud_max = 30
amplitud_min = 5
distancia_max = 200
distancia_min = 50

# Las dos líneas siguientes preparan el pulso en la variable "e"
t = np.linspace(-1, 1, duracion_total, endpoint=False)
i, q, e = signal.gausspulse(t, fc=duracion_total/ancho_pulso, retquad=True, retenv=True)


data = np.zeros(duracion_total)
muerto = np.random.randint(distancia_min, distancia_max)
x = muerto
while x<duracion_total:
  altura = np.random.randint(amplitud_min, amplitud_max)

  # Sumar el pulso desplazado hasta la posición x, y reescalado verticalmente
  data += shift(e*altura, x-duracion_total//2)

  # Preparar la posición x para el siguiente pulso
  x += np.random.randint(distancia_min, distancia_max)
```

El resultado obtenido es ahora:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes jugar con el ancho de los pulsos, pero cuidado, que si casualmente dos caen muy cerca, se "solaparán" creando una especie de montaña con dos jorobas.

Comment: Una preguntica, habría alguna manera de no hacer los pulsos cuadrados? sino más bien hacerlos definidos, algo más o menos como lo que yo logré aquí: https://we.tl/t-Vss0cFutS7, sin embargo lo que yo logré está un poco mal porque no tengo la amplitud ni el tiempo muerto random

Comment: Mira que te lo había preguntado antes por si acaso XD. He pensado un rato y he dado con una idea para generar el tipo de pulsos que buscabas. He actualizado la respuesta.

Comment: Aghh, qué crack jajaja

Comment: Una última preguntica, sabrás de pronto si yo puedo hacer una animación de esos pulsos gaussianos?

Comment: He estado viendo el módulo de animatplot e intenté hacer lo siguiente: 
`block = amp.blocks.Line(data)`
`anim = amp.Animation([block])`
`anim.save_gif('graph_anim.gif')`

Comment: Pero qué es lo que se animaría?

Comment: El recorrido de los pulsos, desde el pulso 1 hasta el último

Comment: Quieres decir que la gráfica se vaya desplazando de derecha a izquierda? O que los pulsos vayan apareciendo? Es que sin verlo o sin explicarlo mejor no lo entiendo

Comment: Tipo así: https://tenor.com/view/life-heart-heart-rate-gif-13946061

Comment: Creo que ya son demasiadas preguntas en una, y la animación ya no "encaja" en el título de la pregunta original. Mejor haces una pregunta nueva sobre cómo crear una animación, e incluyes en esa pregunta un enlace a ésta, y también el ejemplo de la animación que buscas. Así queda más ordenado para otros usuarios del sitio